# how to validate datefield in angular reactive form?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to validate my form in angular using reactive form .There is few fields example `date` and `year` in which user enter  only `number`
 date formate (01 -31) year formate (1990 ---or 2019 four digit number) so he try to enter anything other than string I need to show invalid message .I tried like this

I am looking what is pattern of `date` and `year` pattern

https://codesandbox.io/s/jzq6nn6zz9

```
cardnumber: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]{16}")]],
      dateofexipiredate: ["", [Validators.required]],
      dateofexipireyear: [""],
      cvc: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[0-9]{3}")]]
```

what is pattern of `dateofexipiredate` and `dateofexipireyear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something like the following to cover the spec you have mentioned:

For the year: `Validators.pattern("(199[0-9])|(20[01][0-9])")`

For the date: `Validators.pattern("(0[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[0-1])")`

However, it might be better to consider validating these two together with the month to ensure it is actually a valid date - e.g. there is no 31/02/2013. That would be much harder using just a regular expression though (particularly leap years and so forth).